# Problems with PyUSB in Python 2.7. Do I need LibUSB driver?

Tags: python, pyusb

I installed PyUSB from source for Python 2.7

When I import the module I get no error, but when I try:

```
printers = usb.core.find(find_all=True, bDeviceClass=7)
```

or

```
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x04d8, idProduct=0x003f)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

I'm able to communicate correctly with this device in C#, and was curious why it doesn't appear in PyUSB.

Comment: You should really tell us which OS you're using.

Comment: hey I have the same problem. I am on windows 7. Please help me.